# Select different grails layout for mobile user

Tags: grails, web-applications, mobile

I have a webapp that defines main.gsp as the default layout that is used in all the views and I am using spring-mobile plugin to shift between the mobile and desktop views. But I want to now change between mobile.gsp layout and main.gsp layout for mobile users.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If you have different views for mobiles why can't you just modify those views to use the mobile.gsp layout?  Maybe I'm not understanding.

Comment: I used to have completely different views, but the question that I am posing is that what if i wanted to use the same view but with different layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using Spring Mobile you could use a filter to intercept the controller calls and set the layout:

```
class MobileFilters {
    def filters = {
        mobileFilter(controller:'*', action:'*') {
            afterView = {     
               def layout = "main"
               withMobileDevice {
                   layout = "mobile"
               }
               session.layout = layout
           } 
        }
     }
}
```

And then in your gsps

```
<meta name="layout" content="${session.layout}">
```